# How to gzip several files in Perl one by one

Tags: perl

I have a list of files that I want to compress using Perl. Currently I have this:

```
gzip \@tocompress -> $outputfile
    or die "Failed to compress: $GzipError\n"
```

But I want to iterate over the files and add them one at the time to the compress file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What module are you using?

Comment: I was using `IO::Compress::Gzip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using [IO::Compress::Gzip](http://p3rl.org/IO::Compress::Gzip). Use the `Append` option of `gzip`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Compress::Gzip qw{ gzip $GzipError };

my $outputfile = 'out.gz';
my @tocompress = glob '*.txt';

for my $file (@tocompress) {
    next unless -f $file;
    print STDERR "Adding $file\n";
    gzip($file, $outputfile, Append => 1) or die $GzipError;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!